# Busca em DataGridView populado digitando sobre ele

Tags: c#, datagridview

Possuo um `DataGridView` já com dados recuperados onde o usuário seleciona um item. Mas, como os itens são numerosos, gostaria de possibilitar que o usuário digite sobre o DataGrid enquanto o sistema "vai" até o item digitado.

Não sei o nome correto desse tipo de facilidade, mas é muito comum no próprio ambiente widows. Como aplico isso num `DataGridView`?

Obrigado.

Comment: Como se fosse um CTRL F na página?

Comment: Isso, mas sem o `CTRL` + `F`.. Hehe

Comment: Aonde a pessoa digitaria? no próprio gridview? ou em um campo busca fora?

Comment: No próprio Grid..

Answer (score 1):

Adicione um campo do tipo `TextBox` logo acima do seu `DataGridView` e adicione um manipulador para o evento `TextChanged` e dentro deste manipulador faça como o código abaixo, levando em consideração as suas necessidades:

```
var termo = (sender as TextBox).Text.ToLowerInvariant();
bool semTermo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(termo);

foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if ((linha.Cells[COL_NOME.Index].Value as string).ToLowerInvariant().Contains(termo) || semTermo)
        linha.Visible = true;
    else
        linha.Visible = false;
}
```

Neste exemplo quando o texto do campo for alterado as linhas que contiverem o valor digitado na coluna de "Nome", `COL_NOME` é o nome de uma coluna, serão exibidos. Caso o termo esteja vazio, ou seja, a pessoa tenha apagado, ele exibirá todas as linhas.

Comment: A ideia é interessante, mas ao testar o código tenho o erro "Não foi possível tornar invisível a linha associada à posição do gerenciador de moeda". Tentei adicionar a linha `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null` logo acima de `Visible = False` (solução que achei por aí), mas não funcionou

Comment: "... gerenciador de moeda" você está usando algum componente extra ou não está usando o DGV original?

Comment: Estranho o erro, não? Também não entendi.  Nada de diferente, apenas o velho e quase obsoleto DataGridView..

Comment: Poste a exception em inglês, sem tradução.

Comment: adicionei um pequeno trecho que encontrei [**AQUI**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/d18b3b16-4966-48c5-af8a-ccb528dacba6/erro-ocultando-uma-linha-no-datagridview?forum=vscsharppt) e resolveu o erro, mas o processo num todo demora tempo demais na análise das ROWs. Não haveria uma forma apenas de posicionar o Grid no dado procurado?

Comment: Teria sim, mas acredito que a demora é devido à busca em si e não a ocultação das linhas. Você quer posicionar a célula que for encontrada primeira como a célula visível é isto?

Comment: Minha ideia inicial era não deixar nenhuma `row` invisível, apenas posicionar o item buscado na tela, porém, acabei por fazer uma busca via `TextBox` que realiza uma nova `query` no banco de dados no evento `TextChanged`.